# elsarticle figure to left in LyX

Tags: floats, lyx, align, elsarticle

I use `elsarticle` 2 docment page in LyX.

I put figure in left column partion and use

```
\resizebox{3.4in}{!}{ Figure.png }
```

to make it smaller

But I still need to align the figure to left of the page

How to do this in LyX?

Answer (score 1):

The resizing can already be done in `\includegraphics` with the `width` option. If the figure starts a new paragraph, add `\noindent`. If there are centering commands before (`\centering` or environment `center`), then you might consider removing them. Otherwise it can be put to the left by `\hfill\null`. The `\null` prevents that the `\hfill` is skipped by the paragraph end. A third method uses `\leftline` (unlike `\mbox`) it does not switch into horizontal mode).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \noindent
  \includegraphics[width=3.4in]{Figure}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3.4in]{Figure}\hfill\null
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \leftline{%
    \includegraphics[width=3.4in]{Figure}%
  }
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: `adjustbox` also provides some keys to align images to the right, left or center. They can be exported for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: i don't know how to add this code in lyx, this is the existing code form code viewer but i can't edit it? \begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\resizebox{3.4in}{!}{ \includegraphics[clip]{tae1}}
\par\end{centering}   so how to add the working \includegraphics[width=3.4in]{Figure}\hfill\null